# django adding products to a list via m2m relationship

Tags: python, django

How do I add products into a preexisting list? Any guidance would be most appreciated.

I get the following error:

> ValueError at /core_lists/test_list/
>   Cannot assign "": "ListHasProducts.product" must be a "Product" instance.

models.py

```
    class Product(models.Model):
        brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        url = models.URLField()
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add = True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now = True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
    class List(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add = True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now = True)
        products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ListHasProducts')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class ListHasProducts(models.Model):
        list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
    def testList(request):
        test_form = ProductsForm
        if request.method == 'POST':
            test_form = ProductsForm(request.POST)
            if test_form.is_valid():
                test_form.save()
                ListHasProducts(list=List.objects.get(pk=13), product=test_form)
                ListHasProducts.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('core_lists:test_list'))
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models
I think you should have `related_name` in manytomany property

Comment: @YeganehSalami Thank you for your help. It is appreciated. I do not think I am skilled enough to solve my task. The ```related_name``` help as I can see the site again. However the error has just moved to a browser error.

Answer (score 0):

according to django document

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models

you shoud have `related_name`

```
class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='lists')
```